# Highcharts two charts on page

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

This is probably an easy fix, but I've been fighting with it so long that I just don't "see" it anymore.

Trying to display two charts on one page. One is a column chart containing two comparison groups, and another one is a longitudinal one that displays a timeseries. They are both generated dynamically (that part is working fine), but for the life of me, I can't get them to both display. If I delete one, the other one displays, but not both at the same time.

I would appreciate any help!

Here is the jsfiddle which is giving an error of //]]>, which I really have no idea what it means.

```
<script>
$(function () {
var data = [

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"John", "val":3.0000},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"Julia", "val":4.0000},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"Liz", "val":3.2308},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"Bob", "val":3.3574},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"Chuck", "val":3.0847},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"BillyBob", "val":3.5385},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"Cindy", "val":3.4444},

{"unit":"Apples", "status":"Blanche", "val":3.1992},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"John", "val":3.6000},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"Liz", "val":3.5000},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"Bob", "val":3.5344},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"Chuck", "val":3.4828},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"BillyBob", "val":3.7143},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"Cindy", "val":3.7500},

{"unit":"Oranges", "status":"Blanche", "val":3.4526},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"John", "val":0.0000},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"Liz", "val":0.0000},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"Bob", "val":1.1429},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"Chuck", "val":1.0625},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"BillyBob", "val":0.7500},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"Cindy", "val":1.0000},

{"unit":"Unclassified", "status":"Blanche", "val":1.2500},

];

var datalong = [


{"longunit":"2004", "longstatus":"Apples", "longval":3.2},

{"longunit":"2006", "longstatus":"Apples", "longval":3.2},

{"longunit":"2009", "longstatus":"Apples", "longval":3.3},

{"longunit":"2011", "longstatus":"Apples", "longval":3.4},

{"longunit":"2004", "longstatus":"Oranges", "longval":3.4},

{"longunit":"2006", "longstatus":"Oranges", "longval":3.5},

{"longunit":"2009", "longstatus":"Oranges", "longval":3.5},

{"longunit":"2011", "longstatus":"Oranges", "longval":3.6},

];


var seriesData = [];
var xCategories = [];

var i, cat;
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
cat = data[i].unit;
if(xCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1){
xCategories[xCategories.length] = cat;
}
}

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
if(seriesData){
var currSeries = seriesData.filter(function(seriesObject){ return seriesObject.name == data[i].status;});
if(currSeries.length === 0){
seriesData[seriesData.length] = currSeries = {name: data[i].status, data: []};
} else {
currSeries = currSeries[0];
}
var index = currSeries.data.length;
currSeries.data[index] = data[i].val;
} else {
seriesData[0] = {name: data[i].status, data: [data[i].val]}
}
}


var longseriesData = [];
var longxCategories = [];

var longcat;
for(i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){
longcat = data2[i].unit;
if(longxCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1){
longxCategories[longxCategories.length] = longcat;
}
}


for(i = 0; i < data2.length; i++){
if(longseriesData){
var longcurrSeries = seriesData.filter(function(seriesObject){ return seriesObject.name == data2[i].status;});

if(longcurrSeries.length === 0){
longseriesData[longseriesData.length] = longcurrSeries = {name: data2[i].status, data: []};
} else {
longcurrSeries = longcurrSeries[0];
}
var longindex = longcurrSeries.data2.length;
longcurrSeries.data2[index] = data2[i].val;
} else {
longseriesData[0] = {name: data2[i].status, data: [data2[i].val]}
}
}


var happycontainer;
$(document).ready(function() {
happycontainer= new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'container-happycontainer',
type: 'column'
},
title: {
text: 'column chart'
},
xAxis: {
categories: xCategories
},
yAxis: {
min: 0,
title: {
    text: 'Testing Question 1'
},
stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
    }
}
},

series: seriesData
});
});

});


var long-happycontainer;
$(document).ready(function() {
long-happycontainer= new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'long-container-happycontainer',
type: 'line'
},

colors: ['#0D26E7', '#B20000'],

title: {
text: 'Testing Question 2'
},
xAxis: {
categories: xCategories
},

yAxis: {
min: 0,
title: {
    text: 'Means of Responses'
},
},

plotOptions: {
series: {
lineWidth: 3
}
},
series:  seriesData 

});
});

});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bCU2E/155/

Comment: You have a lot wrong with that jsFiddle. `data2` not defined. Functions declared in loops. Dangling commas, etc. Will try and sort it.

Comment: Can you update your jsfiddle, to be working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clean up your js syntax a lot. But, the main issue is where you are setting index lengths and variable declarations are outside of scope. In jsFiddle you need to remove the `script` tags from your js code block as well. Now, run jsHint - good gravy look at all those red dots. Not bad though, just fix what it tells you to.

Now, the main issue is this part:

```
var longindex = longcurrSeries.data2.length;
longcurrSeries.data2[index] = data2[i].val;
```

This is undefined `longcurrSeries.data2.length` becuase it has no elment of `data2`. You need to do this:

```
var longindex = longcurrSeries.data.length;
longcurrSeries.data[index] = data2[i].val;
```

Fix you other syntax errors (I left the function declared in a loop alone for now) and I would definitely change your variable name for `long-happycontainer` to something more standardized (try not to have operators in var names) and you get this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/gz3z7/).

Comment: Aha! I had a feeling that I butchered the bejeezus out of that. Thank you for your help. I'll try them and see if that fixes it.

Comment: wegeld: I tried your solution, and it works on the first chart, but not the second. The problem is that in the jsFiddle that you did, the second chart is showing the wrong x-axis and y-axis. if you look at the data from var2, the x-axis should be the years, rather than "Apples" and "oranges".

Comment: And here is the updated jsFiddle. No second chart :(

Comment: My JsFiddle didn't post earlier:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/SzY28/). Still no chart showing up. I just copied/pasted what you had after I fixed some of the var names.

Comment: @DrGeek, you removed more than just some var names. You also need to include a reference to jquery. Even after that you have errors. Check your console - `index is not defined`.

Comment: You need to change `longcurrSeries.data[index] = data2[i].val;` to `longcurrSeries.data[longindex] = data2[i].val;`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/SzY28/1/

Comment: You rock! Thank you very much for your help, and your patience. I clearly need to brush up on my javascript. Haven't used it in over 12 years.